# Unity: how NOT to call Update() if [condition]?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Global space I would have:

```
public enum UpdateMode{
EveryFrame,
FixedUpdate
```

}

Then in my script: `UpdateMode updateMode;`

```
private void Update()
{
    if (updateMode != UpdateMode.EveryFrame) { return; }
    MyFunction();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (updateMode != UpdateMode.FixedUpdate) { return; }
    MyFunction();
}
```

But I still don't like the idea that the `Update()` function is still called every frame, this screams unoptimized. I thought about making 2 separate scripts for each case, but a lot of code would repeat, it would be just coping the script, renaming it and Writing `Update/FixedUpdate`. I also thought about making 2 more scripts, one with `Update()` and one with `FixedUpdate()` and then just call `MyFunction()` via reference.

I wanted to know if there was a more elegant way to approach this or which solution would be more performant, both in CPU cycles, memory and complexity.

Thanks anticipated.

Comment: disable according components? [`Behaviour.enabled`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html) .... or in general only implement the one you need in the first place ... what exactly is your use case?

Comment: I don't think you understand how `Update()` works. The Updates are called as long as the function is defined and the component is enabled. You can't "remove" them at runtime. You can only disable the component. You can also not choose which type of `Update()` is running since all of them are running on the engine. To choose which runs on a component simply don't add it. If you want code to not execute, then use `return`. There is no `enum` where you decide how the engine works. And simulating one is not worth it. An empty Update doesn't use memory or CPU since it doesn't have any code in it.

Comment: It might be the case that this is the most performant way to do this. A single enum comparison to early return is really not a lot of cycles, any other solution might easily take just as much time - you'd have to actually benchmark to find out

Comment: *a lot of code would repeat* . How about moving the code in a separate function and calling that from Update or FixedUpdate? Voila, magically no redunant repeating code. If you want separate classes use polymorphism. To me it sounds like there is a design issue where you expect the engine to run in a certain way rather than you working how the engine wants you to. Tell us your use case and maybe we can come up with suggestions. Do **NOT** simulate `Update()` with Coroutines or `InvokeRepeating()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a couroutine that yields for the duration of a frame or a fixed update.

```csharp
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Selected());
}

IEnumerator Selected()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (updateMode == UpdateMode.EveryFrame)
        {
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
        else
        {
            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
        }
        MyFunction();
    }
}
```

Mind that according to the [manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html):

> If a coroutine runs every frame and doesn’t yield on long-running operations, it’s more performant to replace it with an Update or LateUpdate callback. This is useful if you have long-running or infinitely looping coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

You could have some humble object which is delegating out to the logic, but there's no way to tell if it would be acutually faster without benchmarking.

```cs
class Logic
{
    // whatever you want
    public void Foo();
}

class FrameUpdater: Monobehaviour
{
    public Logic logic;

    void Update() => logic.Foo();
}

class FixedUpdater : Monobehaviour
{
    public Logic logic;

    void FixedUpdate() => logic.Foo();
}
```

Then attach both these components to your class and turn them on or off depending on which behaviour you want

```cs
class Controller : Monobehaviour
{
    FrameUpdater frameUpdater;
    FixedUpdater fixedUpdater;

    void Awake()
    {
        frameUpdater = gameobject.AddComponent<FrameUpdater>();
        fixedUpdater = gameobject.AddComponent<FixedUpdater>();

        var logic = new Logic();
        frameUpdater.logic = logic;
        fixedUpdater.logic = logic;

        fixedUpdater.enabled = false;
    }

    void Swap()
    {
        frameUpdater.enabled = !frameUpdater.enabled;
        fixedUpdater.enabled = !fixedUpdater.enabled;
    }

}
```

Comment: I suspect you actually won't gain much of any benifit from this, even if you have a couple thousand of these objects. This really smells like premature optimisation

Comment: yes, but I still think that's an important aspect, since I plan using this in short bursts, between 5s - 30s.

Comment: What's the reason you're switching between the two, the only reason `fixedupdate` exists is so physics works no matter how slow your framerate becomes, what kind of object is sometimes framerate dependant and sometimes phyics step dependant?